# How to assign a "final function "variable"" to "onPressed" method in "textButton" in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

this is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:take3/constants.dart';
import 'package:take3/screens/login/login_screen.dart';
import 'package:take3/screens/signup/signup_screen.dart';

class RoundedButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
final Function press; **//this is the variable!!!**
  final Color color, textColor;
  const RoundedButton({
    super.key,
    required this.text,
    required this.press,
    this.color = kPrimaryColor,
    this.textColor = Colors.white,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
      width: size.width * 0.8,
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(29),
        child: TextButton(
          style: TextButton.styleFrom(
            backgroundColor: color,
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20, horizontal: 40),
          ),
          onPressed: (press) {} **// here is the issue!!!**
              ),
            );
          },
          child: Text(
            text,
            style: TextStyle(color: textColor),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

what is the correct way to write the final function "press" inside "onPressed"?

please help, I am struggling ,,,

I tried to write "press" but it did not work.

note:
I am using "Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 2" on MacOS.
flutter version: flutter 3.13.9
dart version: 3.1.5

Answer (score 1):

There is many way to call the function to `TextButton`, try one of these method.

```
final Function press;
```

1. `onPressed: () => press(),`
2. `onPressed: () {press();},`
3. `onPressed: press,`

the third method is only if the function has the same type with `onPressed`. In `TextButton` `onPressed` have `Function()?` type, and your function type must be `Function()?` too. (this is only for third method)

Example in full code of TextButton:

```
TextButton(
  onPressed: () {press();},
  child: const Text("Button"),
)
```

See more example and explanation on the documentation: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextButton-class.html

Comment: thank you sooooooooooo much, OMG I can't, everything is working now, I am so happy, you are the best thank you again.

Comment: @AljowharahAlbader Your welcome, keep learning matee!